# How to bypass Backup-SqlDatabase prompt for password?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-sql-database, azure-powershell

I'm writing a powershell script to run some sql backups to a network share.  Is there a way to get around the password prompt?

```
Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance $SQLServer -Database $DatabaseName -BackupFile "\\network-share\MainDB.bak" -Credential (Get-Credential "sa")
```

Currently this prompts me for a password. I'd like for these to run automatically without any user intervention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just create a credential object and pass it in as you normally would:

```
$cred = [pscredential]::new('administrator',(ConvertTo-SecureString -String '!Q2w3e4r' -AsPlainText -Force))
Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance $SQLServer -Database $DatabaseName -BackupFile "\\network-share\MainDB.bak" -Credential $cred
```